# How do I remove letters from numeric cells so that I can make the column entirely numeric? (R)

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe with a column full of pixel coordinates. I want to remove the 'px' from these values so that I can make the entire column numeric without introducing NAs.

```
    > print(data_exp_59965_v11_task_j84b$`X Coordinate`)
   [1] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
  [10] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA          
  [19] NA           NA           "-401.222px" "401.222px"  "-200.611px" "347.458px"  "200.611px"  "347.458px"  "-200.611px"
  [28] "-347.458px" "200.611px"  "-347.458px" NA
```

Comment: Something like: `as.numeric(gsub("px", "", data_exp_59965_v11_task_j84b$`X Coordinate`))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sub`:

```r
 df$`X Coordinate` <- as.numeric(sub("px$", "", df$`X Coordinate`, fixed=TRUE))
```

More generally, you might try:

```r
df$`X Coordinate` <- as.numeric(sub(".*?(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", df$`X Coordinate`))
```

This option would capture every number, excluding any remaining content.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

data_exp_59965_v11_task_j84b %>% 
  mutate(`X Coordinate` = as.numeric(str_replace_all(`X Coordinate`, "px$", "")))
```

**Output**

```
  X Coordinate
1     -401.222
2      401.222
3     -200.611
4           NA
5           NA
```

**Data**

```
data_exp_59965_v11_task_j84b <- structure(list(`X Coordinate` = c("-401.222px", "401.222px", 
"-200.611px", NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect use case for `parse_number` from `readr` it is in `tidyverse`:
Data from @AndrewGB (many thanks)

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

data_exp_59965_v11_task_j84b %>% 
  mutate(`X Coordinate` = parse_number(`X Coordinate`))
```

```
  X Coordinate
1     -401.222
2      401.222
3     -200.611
4           NA
5           NA
```